# serialize array returning an empty array

Tags: forms, angularjs, jquery

I'm trying to grab some form data in my function but for some reason my fom returns an empty array when i try and run the function .serializeArray() on it. I've checked that to make sure it input element has a name I just can't figure out why this is happening

this is my form

```
 <form id="uploadForm"  name="form" action="{{nodeSocketUrl}}/upload?tenant=qa&envelope=true" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="forms"  style="left:15px">
                <fieldset class="units-row">
                    <h3>Upload A Presentation</h3>
                    <label for="presentationFileUpload">Select a .ppt, .pptx, .pdf</label>
                        <input type="file" id="presentationFileUpload" name="presentationFile" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().onFileSelect(this)"/>
                    <hr>
                    <input type="submit" id="fileUploadBtn" class="btn btn-primary disabled" value="Upload" ng-click="uploadFile($event)" name="upload">
                </fieldset>
            </form>
```

This is my function which I'm hopping to get the form data from

```
 $scope.uploadFile = function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            //$scope.form.preventDefault();
            var dCheck = $('input[type="file"]').val();
                console.log(e.currentTarget);
                var form = $('#uploadForm').serializeArray();
                console.log(form);
}
```

form returns an empty array any help with this would be appreacited

Answer (score 0):

Why not think in pure angular way?

use can use

```
<input type="file" ng-model="filePath">
```

And next, get the file name in $scope.filePath